# How to establish a database connection on Dbeaver

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am running mysql db as a docker image and everything was built correctly.
My Mysql image is running and I can see the container id but when I try to establish a connection on my workbench I get this error  - **"Public Key Retrieval is not allowed"**

FYI - I passed the password to the db as an env variable in a separate file within the same dir

Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to `Driver properties` tab and set `allowPublicKeyRetrieval` to `true`. More details at [MySQL Connection error with default Driver Properties](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/9565#issuecomment-680773545)
.